# Maximum call stack size exceeded, infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have three Select2 boxes. When I change one, all the not-clicked ones need to be reset. When I do this, it causes an infinite loop and I get the error listed in the title. How can I solve this?

```
var group = $(".searchgroup1");

group.on('change', function(){
    var box = group.index($(this));
    group.each(function(index){
        if(box != index){
            $(this).val(null).trigger("change"); // <-- this resets the <select>
            //If I remove the code up here, the infinite loop disappears
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `trigger` (which is what `click` with no arguments calls) calls the event handlers on the element *synchronously*. Since you're triggering the event you're handling, you're effectively calling your event handler recursively with no get-out clause, so you run out of stack.

Here's proof that the callback is synchronous:

```js
$("#foo").on("click", function() {
  log("Clicked");
});
log("Clicking");
$("#foo").click();
log("Done clicking");

function log(msg) {
  $("<p>").text(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can make the call asynchronous by wrapping it in a `setTimeout`:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.val(null);
setTimeout(function() {
    $this.trigger("change");
}, 0);
```

Comment: How can I solution this?

Comment: @EriksonRodriguez - I say how in the answer.